# How to use an external third party library in Stencil.js

Tags: javascript, web-component, stenciljs, stencil-component

I have a Stencil component and, as part of its business logic, I need to use an external Javascript file `mylib.js`. The Javascript file contains some business logic the Stencil component should use.

Here's my component:

```
import { Component, Element, Prop, h, Host } from '@stencil/core';
import moment from 'moment';
import mylib from 'src/js/mylib.js';

@Component({
  tag: 'dashboard-widget',
  styleUrl: 'dashboard-widget.css',
  shadow: false
})
export class DashboardWidget {

  @Element() el: HTMLElement;

  @Prop() canvas: HTMLElement;
  @Prop() channelName: string = "";
  @Prop() channelValue: string = "";
  @Prop() isBlinking: boolean = true;

  componentDidLoad() {
      console.log(mylib.test());
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Host>
      <div class="card-content card-content-padding">
          <b>{this.channelName}</b>
          <h1 class="dashboard-card-value">{this.channelValue}</h1>
          <canvas class="dashboard-card-canvas"></canvas>
      </div>
      </Host>
    );
  }
}
```

I keep getting the error

> TypeScript Cannot find module 'src/js/mylib.js'.

I tried:

```
import mylib from 'src/js/mylib.js';

import 'src/js/mylib.js';

import 'mylib' from 'src/js/mylib.js';
```

to no avail.

The `mylib.js` file is inside the `js` folder.
The online documentation doesn't mention at all how to import external libraries. I've been successful importing moment.js but only because I installed it first by doing:

```
npm install moment
```

and then importing it inside the component by doing:

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

I also tried to "import" the external JS library by referencing it inside the index.html

```
<script src="assets/js/mylib.js"></script>
```

The library is available outside the component but not inside it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To import files that aren't installed by NPM you can use relative paths prefixed with `./` or `../`:

```
import mylib from '../../js/mylib.js';
```

You can import everything that is exported from that JS file and even use named imports:

**mylib.js**

```
export function someFunction() {
  // some logic
}
```

**dashboard-widget.tsx**

```
import { someFunction } from '../../js/mylib.js`;

const result = someFunction();
```

Comment: it didn't work, still doesn't find the "module". Btw, I don't have any "module", I just have a .js file containing some functions that the Stencil component should use as part of its business logic.

Comment: You need to `export` the functions, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 14):

Since you're mentioning Moment.js, I'll explain how to load that first. It's possible to do it the way you did by importing it inside your component's module, however that will result in a large bundle size because the npm package of moment is not targeted for browsers but for use in Node.js projects where bundle size doesn't matter. Moment.js distributes browser bundles inside the package though. So what you can do is add a copy task to your Stencil output target to copy `node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js` into your build directory:

```js
// stencil.config.ts

import { Config } from '@stencil/core';

export const config: Config = {
  namespace: 'my-app',
  outputTargets: [
    {
      type: 'www',
      copy: [
        {
          src: '../node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js',
          dest: 'lib/moment.min.js'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

Then, as you already tried with your lib, you can load that script in `src/index.html`:

```html
<script src="/lib/moment.min.js"></script>
```

However, your Typescript project won't know yet that `moment` is available in the global scope. That's easy to solve though, you can just add a declaration file somewhere in your project, e. g. `src/global.d.ts` with the content

```js
import _moment from 'moment';

declare global {
    const moment: typeof _moment;
}
```

---

For your test files which run in the Node.js context, not a browser context, you can either import moment or also add `moment` to the global scope, by creating a file (e. g. `jest-setup-file.js`) with the content

```js
global.moment = require('moment');
```

and then in `stencil.config.ts` you just add the `setupFilesAfterEnv` field to `testing`:

```js
{
  testing: {
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest-setup-file.js']
  }
}
```

---

If you don't need the script in your whole application but only when a specific component is loaded, it makes more sense to only load the script from within that component. The easiest way to do that is to create a `script` element and add it to the DOM:

```js
declare const MyLib: any; // assuming that `mylib.js` adds `MyLib` to the global scope

export class MyComp {
  componentWillLoad() {
    const src = "assets/js/mylib.js";

    if (document.querySelector(`script[src="${src}"]`)) {
      return; // already exists
    }

    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = src;

    document.head.appendChild(script);
  }
}
```

Your script/library will most likely also contribute a variable to the global scope, so you'll have to let Typescript know again, which you can do using the `declare` keyword to declare that a variable exists in the global context (see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html#global-variables).

---

As another example, here's a helper I wrote to load the google maps api:

```js
export const importMapsApi = async () =>
  new Promise<typeof google.maps>((resolve, reject) => {
    if ('google' in window) {
      return resolve(google.maps);
    }

    const script = document.createElement('script');

    script.onload = () => resolve(google.maps);
    script.onerror = reject;
    script.src = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${googleApiKey}&libraries=places`;

    document.body.appendChild(script);
  });
```

(The `google` type comes from the `@types/googlemaps` package)

I can then use this like

```js
const maps = await importMapsApi();
const service = new maps.DistanceMatrixService();
```